# Progress bar based on role

Tags: users

I am looking to creating a progress bar on which it is displayed how far you are between role 1 and role 20 (Role names: Level 1 - level 20)?

I take it I would have to use some php or javascript with a hook into the specific users role.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read user roles using below code...

```
global $user;
$user_roles = $user->roles;
$progress_value = x * 5; // where x is value extracted from $user_roles
if( is_numeric($progress_value) && $progress_value > 0 && $progress_value <= 100 ) {
  $style = "width: ".round($progress_value)."%; display: block";
}
print '<div id="progress-wrapper">
  <div id="progress-value" style="<?php print $style; ?>"></div>
<div>';
```

Now the solution needs some CSS to make it look like a progress bar. Start with a basic style - just a black border with a gray filling:

```
<style>
#progress-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100px;
  height: 16px;
}
#progress-value {
  background-color: #acacac;
  height: 16px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a bunch!

But where do I put all this? (Yes I'm a newbie)

Comment: Do I just place it within a block for instance?

Comment: Yes, You can use a block either using php filter or block implemented using a custom module.. Since you are a newbie i would suggest block using php filter..

Comment: You are welcome..  If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation"

Comment: Aight thank you! You helped me a step closer to completing my page - such thanks ;-)